# Change custome theme magento in backoffice not working

Tags: magento

I have installed new theme in magento , to change the default theme i did this in backoffice  of magento, in Design onglet of configuration tab  , but whene i saved this and clear the cache , this not working so have you any idea about the matter and what wrong thing i did , please help me to slove this?

Comment: I think my magento is forced to load just one theme , so how to fixe this  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by changing the name of theme so whene magento looking for this theme can't find it so it take the value setted in backoffice

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to know the fall back model of magento.According to which magento checks for the files in your theme in "app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme"if it doesnot find it there it will look in "app/design/frontend/default/default".If it doesnot find it there than it will search in "app/design/frontend/base/default/default".

You can learn more about theming in magento in magento knowledge base.The main thing is if you want to modify your theme you can easily do it from "app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme".

Hope this will help.